# How to group express routes like express-group-routes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, express, express-router

I tried with **express-group-routes** and works very well on my localhost but does not detect any routes when is started on a docker container

I have simple code that returns JSON as follows:

```
{
    "message": "Service Running"
}
```

and other routes.

The small Expressjs service is working great with `node src/server.js` on Ubuntu and every routes are found.

**The problem comes when I containerize the code.**

The DockerFile looks like this

```
FROM node:12.18.2-alpine3.12

ENV PORT=3000

EXPOSE ${PORT}

COPY . /app

WORKDIR /app

RUN npm install

CMD ["node", "src/server.js"]
```

The server.js looks like this

```js
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const app = express();

// parse requests of content-type: application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// parse requests of content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

var { router } = require('./routes/index');

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.use(router);

app.listen(port,() => console.log("Server started :::", new Date().getTime()));
```

and the route file looks like this

```js
const util = require('../util/util');
const auth = require("../controllers/authController.js");
const app = require('express');
const { check, validationResult, query } = require("express-validator");
const router = app.Router();
require('express-group-routes');
module.exports = (router) => {
    router.group('/api', (router) => {

        router.get("/", (req,res) => {
            return res.status(200).send({ message: "Service Running" });
        });


        router.get("/users", (req, res) => {
            const errors = validationResult(req);
            if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
                return util.ResponseUtil.generateResponseJSON(res, 503, 'Error in validation', { errors: errors.mapped() });
            } else {
                auth.userInfo(req, res);
            }
        });

    });
}
```

1. when running the docker container
   `docker run -it -p 3000:3000 service:latest`
2. The app is running and I get
   `Server started ::: 1594299481981`
3. I'm trying to `GET http://localhost:3000/api/`
4. It returns me

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Error</title>
</head>

<body>
    <pre>Cannot GET /api/</pre>
</body>

</html>
```

**What I tried**

- Use Node 10
- Use Node 12

Comment: Could you try this https://github.com/jrichardsz/nodejs-express-snippets/blob/master/01-hello-world.js instead of your sample?

Comment: it doesn't use the express router. I need that package, but let me try it should work

Comment: @JRichardsz yes it's working with `app.get`

Comment: **express-group-routes** https://github.com/dirkgroenen/express-group-routes/blob/master/index.js uses express in background. Also I can see that is not actively maintained (4 years ago) also its npm site https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-group-route does not have a github repository!

Comment: Does that work with docker?

Comment: If you agree, change title of your question to something like: express-group-routes does not works with docker? Your container has nodejs 12, what version is in your developer machine?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-group-routes this it the right NPM package you forgot the S

Comment: I have the same exact version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**express-group-routes** is not actively maintained (4 years ago)

Also its npm site https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-group-routes  does not have a github repository!

Try to use this snippet:

https://github.com/jrichardsz/nodejs-express-snippets/blob/master/hello-world.js

In which I show you a basic example of routes.

If you want to group your routes you could use something like this:

**server.js**

```
const app = require('express');
const AdminRoute = require ...
const UserRoute = require ...
....
AdminRoute.configure(app)
UserRoute.configure(app)
```

Or this

```
  fs.readdirSync(`/some/folder/routes/`).forEach(function(file){
    var commandRequire = require(`/some/folder/routes/`+file);
    var command = new commandRequire();
  });
```

In which I read js files from a folder and I instantiate them dynamically, so your server.js will be more reduced:

```
const app = require('express');
const ScanRoutes = require ...
...
ScanRoutes.scan("routes/folder", app)
```